# C++ on Jupyter Notebook for Windows

Tags: c++, installation, jupyter-notebook

Has anyone successfully installed and used C++ on Jupyter Notebook on a windows machine? The installation instruction [here](https://github.com/QuantStack/xeus-cling) never worked for me.

```
conda install -c conda-forge xeus-cling
```

gives me

> "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:"

If anyone has succeeded in installing on Windows, could you please share your instructions? Thanks.

Comment: The usual advice is to dump windows, but it is not easy on linux either. I just wrote my [own](https://github.com/user1095108/jupyter-gpp-kernel) kernel and you can do the same.

Answer (score 2):

The "issue" is that `conda-forge/xeus-cling` isn't available for Windows (yet?) (as indicated on [this](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/xeus-cling) page of `conda-forge/xeus-cling` on anaconda.org). You can instead use [gouarin/xeus-cling](https://anaconda.org/gouarin/xeus-cling) (you still have to have the compatible environment, though). Of course, the online [C++ Jupyter Notebook](https://hub.gke.mybinder.org/user/quantstack-xeus-cling-ncemy5jv/notebooks/notebooks/xcpp.ipynb) is available too.

Comment: the binder page is no longer available and the gouarin/xeus-cling also doesn't get installed in windows 10.


EDIT: Updated binder link: https://notebooks.gesis.org/binder/jupyter/user/quantstack-xeus-cling-prpmrmmj/notebooks/notebooks/xcpp.ipynb

Comment: Nonee of this works!